# pandas: Subclass dataframe and cast with `astype`

Tags: python, pandas, subclass

I have the following subclassed dataframe called `AirrTable`

```
class AirrTable(pd.DataFrame):
    """
    Object oriented AirrTable

    Raises
    ------
    MissingAirrColumns
        If there is any missing columns from the airr standards


    Examples
    --------

    Pass in pandas dataframe
    >>> df = pd.read_csv("tests/fixtures/heavy_lev_sample.csv.gz")
    >>> at = AirrTable(df)
    """

    _metadata = ["_suffixes", "_islinked"]

    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, key_column="sequence_id", **kwargs):
        super(AirrTable, self).__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)
        if not isinstance(data, pd.core.internals.managers.BlockManager):
            # when data != BlockManager, we are being constructed for the First Time
            if self.__class__ is AirrTable:
                self._islinked = False
                self._key_column = key_column
                self._suffixes = []
                self._verify() # this method does lots of data verification and sets _verify


    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return AirrTable

    @property
    def verified(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_verified"):
            return False
        return self._verified
```

So the problem I'm having is that I have some data types I'm trying to cast somewhere in the constructor.

```
def _verify(self):
   print(type(self))
   self = self.astype({'some_field':'float','some_other_field':str})
   print(type(self))

Output:
<class 'airrtable.AirrTable'>
<class 'pandas.core.DataFrame'>
```

However, it seems that the astype method is returning the `pd.DataFrame` and not my AirrTable class. Any suggestions on how to coerce the datatypes in a custom subclass like this?

Comment: Did you try `self = AirrTable(self.astype({'some_field':'float','some_other_field':str})`?

Comment: That will call the constructor again and I'll be in another loop won't I?

Comment: When you use `df = df.astype(...)` you receive a new instance of DataFrame. It's the same for you, that's why you receive a DataFrame. You have to return a new instance of AirrTable. You should take a look to GeoPandas source code.

Comment: Yes, I can see I'm getting back a `pd.concat` copy. I'm wondering how not to. YOur solution is just thumb through the GeoPandas code eh?

Comment: For example, you can check [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/831108dcb369517e311cd0ee3821db1f2fb7122d/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L1718-L1741) and [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/831108dcb369517e311cd0ee3821db1f2fb7122d/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L1743-L1769) for example.

Comment: overriding astype is brilliant!

Comment: I hope you found the solution to your problem now.